# How to rotate image or sprite along X or Y axis in Cocos2d, Objective-c, or in a popular or free mac image editor?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

If you visit the following link, it may be easier to understand what I am trying to accomplish:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/08/02/rotating-an-image-along-its-x-axis-y-axis-and-z-axis-in-flex-and-flash-player-10/

In cocos2d it is easy to rotate an image along the z-axis. What I am trying to do is rotate along the X or Y axis as illustrated in the link (if you slide the sliders of rotationX or rotationY).

Being able to do this programmatically in cocos2d would be ideal, but if I could even do this in a free or low-cost mac image editor it would solve my problem, as I could then save the images and just animate them in cocos2d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

CCFiniteAction* foo = [CCActionTween actionWithDuration:1.0 key:@"scaleX" from:1.0 to:-1/0];
[sprite runAction:foo];

You can also flip along "x" axis by using "scaleY" instead of scaleX

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the [camera](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_camera.html) property of the CCSprite to change the 3-dimensional orientation of the sprite.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Apparently you can't use world coordinates or rotation / scale / position properties if you are using the camera, and you can't use it if it is part of a CCSpriteBatchNode. My sprites are part of a spriteBatchNode, hence this solution may not be for me. Do you have any sample code? The documentation doesn't say how to rotate along any axis.